# Calculate distance using google map given a latitude and longitude

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, gis

I am developing a desktop application and I have two point (latitude, longitude). How can I get the distance between these two points? I have looked at the API and most of them are javascript or web based. I am not developing a web page. How can I do this in java?

I want a road distance, not a straight distance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've got the latitude and longitude, you can use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance between them - assuming you want "straight line" distance.

EDIT: Okay, now you've actually told us what you want, I suspect you need to use the [Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/). You'll need to make a web request to the appropriate URL with your parameters, specifying either XML or JSON output - which you'll then need to parse.

Note that "JSON" != "Javascript-based". Think of JSON as a data serialization format which just happens to be executable Javascript.

Comment: This question was asked recently in the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/distance-between-lat-long-points) site. The answer with the most votes so far also suggested using the haversine formula.

Comment: I actually don't want to calculate the straight distance.. I want the road distance

Comment: sorry about that, so in this XML http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=1510%20E.9th%20St,%20Tucson,AZ&destination=1610%20E.%2010th%20St,%20Tucson,AZ&sensor=false, which one is the total distance... there is a bunch of distance tag

Comment: @EquinoX: You could add up the values within each step, or just take the distance in the leg itself. Basically, read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google gave me this: http://www.postalcodeworld.com/samples/distance.java.html Looks like this is a pretty good implementation of what you need using the Haversine Formula I think.

Answer (score 0):

This Great Circle Distance code above is probaby OK for most apps. If you need great deal of precision, though, be aware that it may fail in some edge cases due to the earth not being a perfect sphere. In that case you're talking about more complicated algorithms.